# Multiple "Http proxy" addresses for load functions?

Tags: http-proxy

I have multiple `HTTP proxy` addresses, and I want to implement the load function through a new address and port, obtaining resources from different `HTTP proxy` addresses through polling. How? `LVS` or other tools?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious in the http-proxy domain, but this seems very vague. Can you provide more details about what else is involved in this situation?

Comment: @SamStorie I've been using haproxy solved my problem, and the emphasis is on a knowledge point, namely "HTTP proxy" belongs to the application layer of the OSI model, so you need to use the HTTP layer 7 mode, and can not use 4 layer of TCP/UDP transport layer mode.

Thanks!